Fire and Forget with database connection or Hangfire?
We have some task that have to be done on our Gateways. All the new queued task from which get started by our Users are written in to the Database and get fired every 30s by a BackgroundService. The Background Service is then running the RunJobManager() Function.
public async Task RunJobManager()
{
    // This context is in the scope of the JobManager
    // Get a list of IDs of only gateways with an active job
    var gatewaysWithActiveJob = _context.Gateways
        .Where(g => g.Type == GatewayType.Owa4x)
        .Include(g => g.Jobs)
        .Where(_gatewayHasActiveJob)
        .Where(_jobIsNotStarted)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var gateway in gatewaysWithActiveJob)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(() => ExecuteActiveJobAsync(gateway.Id));
        gateway.GetMostRecentJob().JobExectionDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    _context.Gateways.UpdateRange(gatewaysWithActiveJob);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Now we fire/execute an active job and forget about it's thread but tell the Database that we the job is started. The reason why we dont await the Task is, because there can be Jobs that taking minutes (for example uploading files to the Gateway). But we can't block this for minutes, otherwise we get some complaines from user, for example, why his gateway activation is not going through.
So, each active job (thread) then has it's own context, which has a connection to the Database and can update a job, if there is any Error or if it is completed.
private async Task ExecuteActiveJobAsync(Guid gatewayId)
{
    // Caution: do not use members other than the scopeFactory as each thread shall have its own scope
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        await using var scopedContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SuncarContext>();
        // Below: Task that will be done in this job
    }
}

So that means, we dont completely forget about the Task. But, there is one way how the task could be lost and that is if we restart the System. So in this case, we always check in the beginning when the BackgroundService get initialized at the startup if there are some StartedJobs that are not finished. Those we will be requeued.
Now a collegue of mine came to me and sayed, he found a stack overflow post, where it is saying, that we should not use fire and forget. (Fire and forget, using Task.Run or just calling an async method without await) We should rewrite our code and change to Hangfire. I see hangfire are optimized for background tasks, but aren't background services with threads which are started but no await that are connected to the database also a good way to go?

Are you sure you need any kind of fire and forget? What does ExecuteActiveJobAsync really do? UpdateRange isn't needed at all, EF already tracks all those objects and knows they've been updated. The actual UPDATE commands are executed by SaveChangesAsync. As for Hangfire, you can only ask it to start a child job with some data, you don't provide scopes to it

In any case ExecuteActiveJobAsync isn't a job at all, it's just another async method called in an unusual way. If SuncarContext is another DbContext, it will cause delays instead of improving performance. Retrieving eg Gateway objects one by one in parallel isn't any faster than loading all of them at once if the query uses an index eg, sunContext.Gateways.Where(g=>gatewayIds.Contains(g.Id)).ToListAsync();

If you want to start a background job you can use BackgroundJob.Enqueue but pay attention to what the docs say. Hangfire won't execute the job, it will serialize the expression you passed to Enqueue along with its data and start executing a new job. That means the data you pass to the new job must be serializable. gatewaysWithActiveJob is serializable as a list of GUIDs.

Related: Web Api - Fire and Forget.

@TheodorZoulias Yes, it is an ASP.NET application
